# Registered CellInfo List is relative to inverted SubscriptionInfo List?

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I'm currently developing an app that will display network information about all SIM cards inserted.
The problem is carrier-name and network information are obtained from SubscriptionManager and TelephonyManager respectively.

I tried cross-referencing **MNC codes** from SubscriptionManager and TelephonyManager, but it didn't suffice. After meddling a little, I noticed that the Lists generated by both managers seem to be reversed, as if the information from the SIM card inserted in the last slot was contained within the first index of the cells List returned from `getAllCellInfo` method, and contained within the last index of the List returned from `activeSubscriptionList` method.

Can anyone confirm this? Could I trust that it'll always behave this way?

**Basically, I want to know if the cell indexes in the list returned from `TelephonyManager.getAllCellInfo()` is correlated with SIM slot numbers.**

I'm using Android API 24.

Unfortunately, I'm not allowed to post my whole code...
Anyway, here's how I get only registered cells from TelephonyManager:
(This method is called with `TelephonyManager.getAllCellInfo()` method as argument)

```
private ArrayList<CellInfo> updateCellInfo(ArrayList<CellInfo>  cellInfo)
{
    //Create new ArrayList
    ArrayList<CellInfo> cellInfos= new ArrayList<>();

    //If cellular network information list has at least 1 cell information, store only those
    //which are registered
    if(cellInfo.size()!=0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < cellInfo.size(); i++)
        {
            int index=0;
            CellInfo temp=cellInfo.get(i);
            if (temp.isRegistered())
            {
                cellInfos.add(index, temp);
                index++;
            }
        }
    }

    return cellInfos;
}
```

And this is how I relate carrier-names and `cellInfo` together:
(at this point, the ArrayList cellInfo, which contains all registered cells information is reversed, by using the method `Collections.reverse(cellInfo)`)
(cellIndex is the index of the cell information being displayed, relative to the previously generated ArrayList)

```
private String getCarrierName(int cellIndex)
{
        String[] carriers;
        String carrier=getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.not_registered);
        //get subscription manager from activity
        final SubscriptionManager subscriptionManager = SubscriptionManager.from(getActivity());

        //get active subscription list
        final List<SubscriptionInfo> activeSubscriptionInfoList = subscriptionManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoList();

        //if there's at least 1 subscription
        if (activeSubscriptionInfoList != null)
        {
            carriers = new String[activeSubscriptionInfoList.size()];
            if (activeSubscriptionInfoList.size() != 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < activeSubscriptionInfoList.size(); i++)
                {
                    //get carrier names and their respective mnc codes for all subscribed networks
                    carriers[i] = activeSubscriptionInfoList.get(i).getDisplayName().toString();
                }
            }
            carrier=carriers[cellIndex];
        }
    return carrier;
}
```

Comment: for clarity please add version and OS system info and build.

Comment: @ZF007, thanks for answering! Check my edit...

Comment: No need to use the wording edit1 at this stage. BTW... if you post your code its easier to look at the issue and provide a solution by others as well. That will speedup the discovery and remove the teeth grinding and pacing in your living-room or study... ;-)

Comment: @ZF007, just posted some of my code...

Comment: its good you post only the relevant info where its about.. hope you get helped soon. (my question-review to get you going ends here). GL.

Comment: Thanks for your review!